Do ROS2 timers run before starting timer?
Do ROS2 timers run once before starting the timing period or do they only run after the the timer has expired? Is there a way to get the do - while behavior?

The timers will start once the timer has been initialised. In this example  the timer will be started on the timer_ initialisation.

Ok but to clarify, will the timer callback function be called immediately upon reset or will it happen after the timer expires?

By default the timer will start once the timer expires. If the reset timer being called the timer will reset and timer will start from beginning.

See this discourse thread for more info on timer behavior.
The timer callback is triggered only after the first timer period has lapsed.
As somewhat of an ugly hack (but which might be satisfactory for your use case), you could start your timer with a very small period so it is triggered almost instantly, and then in the first callback cancel it and instantiate a new timer, similar to this previous question: How do you change a ROS2 WallTimer period after initialization?.
If not, give some more info on your specific use case.
